# Set display All by default in backend for category/menu/module

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator

Do you have any idea how I could set by default "display All" instead of "display 20"? I would need it for category manager, menu manager, and module manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a global setting for all lists in the Global Configuration of Joomla.
Global Configuration -> Site -> Default List Limit.

There you can specify your list limit. This will be the default for all lists.
However there is no "All" option.
If you need to set it to all, you will have to "hack" a bit the component.

The file you need is in:
/administrator/components/com_config/model/form/application.xml

Line around 715, you will see the select field for the default list limit.

```
<field
    name="list_limit"
    type="list"
    default="20"
    label="COM_CONFIG_FIELD_DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT_LABEL"
    description="COM_CONFIG_FIELD_DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT_DESC"
    filter="integer">
    <option value="5">J5</option>
    <option value="10">J10</option>
    <option value="15">J15</option>
    <option value="20">J20</option>
    <option value="25">J25</option>
    <option value="30">J30</option>
    <option value="50">J50</option>
    <option value="100">J100</option>
</field>
```

You need to add the JALL option like below

```
<field
    name="list_limit"
    type="list"
    default="20"
    label="COM_CONFIG_FIELD_DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT_LABEL"
    description="COM_CONFIG_FIELD_DEFAULT_LIST_LIMIT_DESC"
    filter="integer">
    <option value="5">J5</option>
    <option value="10">J10</option>
    <option value="15">J15</option>
    <option value="20">J20</option>
    <option value="25">J25</option>
    <option value="30">J30</option>
    <option value="50">J50</option>
    <option value="100">J100</option>
    <option value="JALL">JALL</option>
</field>
```

Be aware that you will have to maintain this modification after any updates.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't find the folder model in /administrator/components. My websites are under Joomla 3 and 2.5 and this folder is in neither of them.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: /administrator/components/com_config/model/form/application.xml

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! I am pushing it a bit: is there a way to set category manager, menu manager, and module manager to ALL and article manager to 20?